# Rows are not deleting in the admin grid

Tags: database, delete, custom-admin-grid

class Delete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
/**
* @var \Webkul\Grid\Model\GridFactory
*/
var $postFactory;

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Webkul\Grid\Model\GridFactory $gridFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Stathmos\HelloWorld\Model\PostFactory $postFactory
) 
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->postFactory = $postFactory;
}

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    if (!$data) {
        $this->_redirect('stathmos_helloworld/post/index');
        return;
    }
    try {              

        $rowData = $this->postFactory->create();
              //  $rowData->addData($data)->save();

        $rowData->setData($data);
        // if (isset($data['id'])) {
        //     $rowData->setEntityId($data['id']);
        // }
        $rowData->delete();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Row data has been successfully deleted.'));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
    }
    $this->_redirect('stathmos_helloworld/post/index');
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Stathmos_HelloWorld::delete');
}
```

}

namespace Stathmos\HelloWorld\Ui\Component\Listing\Post\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Action extends Column {

```
/** Url path */
const URL_PATH_EDIT = 'helloworld/post/edit';
const URL_PATH_DELETE = 'helloworld/post/delete';
const URL_PATH_VIEW = 'helloworld/post/view';

protected $actionUrlBuilder;
protected $urlBuilder;

public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context, 
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, 
    UrlInterface $urlBuilder, 
    array $components = [], 
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
}

public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            $name = $this->getData('name');
            if (isset($item['post_id'])) {
                $item[$name]['edit'] = [
                    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            self::URL_PATH_EDIT, [
                                'id' => $item['post_id']
                            ]
                    ),
                    'label' => __('Edit')
                ];
                $item[$name]['delete'] = [
                    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            self::URL_PATH_DELETE, [
                                'id' => $item['post_id']
                            ]
                    ),
                    'label' => __('Delete'),
                    'confirm' => [
                        'title' => __('Delete "${ $.$data.title }"'),
                        'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete a "${ $.$data.title }" record?')
                    ]
                ];
                $item[$name]['preview'] = [
                    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            self::URL_PATH_VIEW, [
                                'id' => $item['post_id']
                            ]
                    ),
                    'label' => __('View')
                ];
            }
        }
    }

    return $dataSource;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following way:

```
$rowData = $this->postFactory->create();
$rowData->load($id) // id is the deleted post id
$rowData->delete();
```

[Here is an example](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Page/Delete.php#L38)

You should use the repository for CRUD operation.

Comment: Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.
it is giving this and redirecting to the dashboard

Comment: Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.
its not deleting

Comment: Don't post data. Check the simple CMS module from magento. Your key related error leads to your security key is missing or wrong.

Comment: I found it error was it was not getting the right url for the controller. Please suggest me for the edit module how I can edit the row?